# How do I set the selection border color in Flex Spark Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, skinning

I have a custom skin applied to a Flex 4 spark datagrid. One really annoying issue I am having is finding the ability to override or change the selected row border color. I was able to set the selectionColor just fine but the border is still the default light blue color. I need it to be yellow.

Anyone know where I can find this style or override this border that is being set when selection happens within the skin itself.

thanks,
-Matthew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's the caretColor style. If not, you can do this:

Create a skin file for the spark datagrid based on spark.skins.spark.DataGridSkin
Now yous hould have a copy of the DataGrid skin, change the following code,

```
 <s:stroke>
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:SolidColorStroke id="caretIndicatorFill" color="0x0167FF" weight="1"/>
 </s:stroke>
```

Change 0x0167FF to the desired color..

Comment: they should call caretColor something like selectedBorderColor

Comment: Agreed, the "caret" terminology has shown up quite a bit in Spark I've noticed.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but FYI there is no need to edit the skin, there is a style `caretColor` on spark DataGrid:

```
<s:DataGrid caretColor="0xffffff" ...
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This does not show up in the code completion and shows this error, The style 'caretColor' is only supported by type 'DataGrid' with the theme(s) 'spark'. But it still works with warning when I declare it in CSS. I'm guessing because I'm creating a mobile app and thus using the mobile theme.